# How do i get the audio to play in a ListView in android Studio?

Tags: java, android

When it open in the emulator and i click on it the audio doesn't play. I've tried on several computers. I add a toast and the toast showed but audio didn't work. 
    The mediaPlayer is declared already.

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, socialArrayPhrases);
    socialPhrases.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    socialPhrases.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position_of_phrase, long ld) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), socialArrayPhrases.get(position_of_phrase), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (position_of_phrase == 0) {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SpanishSocialPhrases.this, R.raw.audio);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To play the sound from [MediaPlayer] , you need the following code :

```
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Your modified code :

```java
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, socialArrayPhrases);
        socialPhrases.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        socialPhrases.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position_of_phrase, long ld) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), socialArrayPhrases.get(position_of_phrase), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (position_of_phrase == 0) {
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SpanishSocialPhrases.this, R.raw.audio);
                        mediaPlayer.setLooping(false); // Loop
                        mediaPlayer.start(); // Play Sound !
                    }

                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!! I have been struggling with this for a long while. Yes i am new. Thank you !

Comment: I have another issue. So i want to add new directories that have audio in it. the only File that can be created is raw.Why? i try adding new directories but they never show up even when i add the audios inside.

Comment: I did not understand exactly what you mean ! but I understand that you want to read music from another directory [ It's not possible ] , the raw folder is for media [ music file , txt file , video file , and etc ... ],If you want to use music without this folder [raw], it's impossible ! , It's better to put all the songs in the raw folder and use it ! And you can not create another folder in the raw folder.if you have other questions that you do not understand, please ask :)